# Entrypoint can't execute command

Tags: docker

I don't understand why my entrypoint can't execute my command. My entrypoint look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

...

exec "$@"
```

My script is existing I can run it when I go inside my container:

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 512 mars  25 09:07 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 512 mars  25 09:07 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 128 mars  25 10:05 entrypoint.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 481 mars  25 09:07 init-dev.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 419 mars  25 10:02 migration.sh
root@0c0062fbf916:/app/scripts# pwd
/app/scripts
```

And when I run my container : `docker run my_container "scripts/migration.sh"`

I got this error:

`scripts/entrypoint.sh: line 8: /app/scripts/migration.sh: No such file or directory`

I have the same error if I just run `ls -all`

```
docker run my_container "ls -all"
exec: ls -all: not found
```

I'm switching linux to windows <-> windows to linux so I checked to change lf to crlf but there is no changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first command doesn't work because your scripts are in `/app/scripts` (note the plural), but you're trying to run run `script/migration.sh`. Additionally, it's not clear what the current working directory is in your container: even if you wrote `scripts/migration.sh`, that would only work if either (a) your `Dockerfile` contains a `WORKDIR /app`, or if your `docker run` command line includes `-w /app`. You would be better off using a fully qualified path:

```
docker run mycontainer /app/scripts/migration.sh
```

Your second example (`docker run my_container "ls -all"`) is over-quoted and would *never* work. You need to write `docker run my_container ls -all`, except that `-all` isn't actually an option that `ls` accepts, although it will work by virtue of being the combination of the `-a` and `-l` options.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I made a typo while I'm writting my question sorry. The problem is the `""` you're right. I want to run my migrations script while I'm running my docker image. I'm using `app-engine-exec-wrapper` and I have problems to use it because I got the not found error as I say. If you check this https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ruby-docker/blob/master/app-engine-exec-wrapper/execute.sh at the end of the file exec wrapper write the command inside `"$@"` that is why I'm trying to place `""` on the command but it doesn't work. I don't know how to manage this so

Comment: ok so it works if I remove `""` from `exec$@` in my entrypoint. I'm not sure if it's good to not surround `$@` by double quote but it works now thank you

Comment: Removing the quotes around `"$@"` is the wrong solution (your script will not handle arguments containing whitespace correctly). See e.g. [the "special parameters" section of the bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters) for more information about the difference between `$@` and `"$@"`. If you're confident you're never going to encounter this situation, maybe it's fine.

Comment: Ok thank you I understand. So I found another way I replaced `"$@"` double quote and and in my pipeline cloud build I can specify the args like this : `'--', 'scripts/migration.sh', '--config=$_MIGRATION_CONFIG'` before I didn't split args by comma `,` I did `'--', 'scripts/migration.sh --config=$_MIGRATION_CONFIG'` all in once. So now it works. Thank you very much !